# Regular Expression query

Tags: c#, regex

Please tell the regular expression for checking words that contains except `/\:*?"<>|`
Also please tell I am trying

```
[a-z0-9A-Z]*^[:*?\"<>|]+[a-z0-9A-Z]*
```

what this is doing?.. 
Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your question: "words that contains except" doesn't make sense.

Comment: clarify please...u want those characters to appear or not ?

Comment: Why dont u just ask your regex query rather than "What this is doing ?"

Comment: I dont want the characters :*?\"<>|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try with:

```
^[^/\:*?"<>|]+$
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression:

```
[a-z0-9A-Z]*^[:*?\"<>|]+[a-z0-9A-Z]*
```

is broken down into comparisions.

Firstly:

```
a-z0-9A-z
```

this matches all characters that are between a-z, 0-9 and A-Z in the alphabet

Then:

```
 [<snip>]*
```

this matches more 0 or more i.e. it will match 0 or more characters between a-z, 0-9 and A-Z.

Then '^' means start of line and '+' means match 1 or more i.e. it will fail with 0 matches whereas '*' will pass.

Apply the above to your expression and you can see what it matches.

Comment: I couldnt find any matching string ? did u ?

Comment: Nope. None that I could find.

Answer (score 0):

i think u need to add "\" symbol inside the bracket as * ? ^ are having special meaning    ^[^/\:*?"<>|]

try it i am not sure........